# Discrepancies with setting state values in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm starting out React JS and following this little exercise, https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html.

It's fairly simple, but I'm facing a huge discrepancy when setting the state value. When I set the state, I view it in the console by doing this: `console.log("s: "+this.state.userInput);`. And I also display it in the view with `{this.state.userInput}`. Fairly simple. But not really. The event and the state value always seem to be a letter apart in the console, but it is perfectly displayed in the view. How is that even possible?!

I wanted to query my server whenever the state changes, but the state is always a letter behind. It's so weird. Could someone please explain to me what this is? And how I can avoid it?

Here's the code.

```
var SearchContainer = React.createClass({
getInitialState: function() {
  return {userInput: ''};
},

handleChange: function(e) {
    console.log("e: "+e.target.value);
    this.setState({userInput: e.target.value});
    console.log("s: "+this.state.userInput);
},

clearAndFocusInput: function() {
  this.setState({userInput: ''}); // Clear the input
  // We wish to focus the <input /> now!
},

render: function() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div onClick={this.clearAndFocusInput}>
        {this.state.userInput}
      </div>
      <input
        value={this.state.userInput}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
});
```

And this is the weird output,

Console:
[image: console]

View: (HTML Page)

[image: HTML]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the state hasn't been updated yet.  Even though you've explicitly set it using `this.setState`, it won't be set until the method has finished executing.

If you need the new value you could always use it from `e.target.value`.

Answer (score 0):

By default, React components re-render when their state is changed.

Therefore, in order to get an accurate reading of the state at a given point, place your console statement inside of the render function, like so:

```
var SearchContainer = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function () {
    return {
      userInput: ''
    };
  },

  handleChange: function(event) {
    var value = event.target.value;
    console.log('Value is ' + value);

    this.setState({
      userInput: value
    });
  },

  clearAndFocusInput: function() {
    this.setState({
      userInput: ''
    });
  },

  render: function() {
    var userInput = this.state.userInput;
    console.log('State is ' + userInput);

    return (
      <div>
        <div onClick={this.clearAndFocusInput}>
          {userInput}
        </div>
        <input
          value={userInput}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: Yes. But I want to call another function that depends on the accuracy of the state. I ended up using refs to find the value of the DOM element.